# How can I alter a smalldatetime column with a default to be datetime?

Tags: sql-server, constraints, default, alter

I have a number of columns in my database that were originally created as `smalldatetime` and that really need to be `datetime`.  Many of these columns were created with the DDL:

```
[columnname] smalldatetime not null default getdate()
```

...which means that in order to alter the column's type, I first have to drop the default, and then re-create the default after altering it.

Of course, I didn't specify a name for the default in the DDL, so the columns all have defaults with names like `DF__CaseLock__CaseCo__182C9B23`.  And when my application creates its database, it does so by executing a script, so the names of the defaults in my customers' databases are (I'm guessing; I haven't verified this) different from their names in mine.

And even if I know the name of the default constraint, I can't figure out the syntax for adding it back in after I drop it.  In fact, it's not clear to me that it's *possible* to add a default constraint to an existing column.

It appears that what I have to do is something like this:

```
declare @t table (id int not null primary key, date smalldatetime null)
insert into @t (id, date)
    select id, date_column from my_table
drop constraint constraint_name
alter table my_table drop column date_column;
alter table my_table add date_column datetime default getdate()
update my_table set date_column = t.date FROM my_table m JOIN @t t ON m.id = t.ID
```

...only I can only write that script if I know what `constraint_name` is, because I can't drop a column that's referenced in a constraint.

Is this really that hard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a default constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_DefaultName DEFAULT 'Default Value' FOR ColumnName
```

You can interrogate the sys tables to find the existing constraints.    When you add them back in, you should provide an explicit name for them.  [Here's a blog post](http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-drop-unnamed-constraint-in-sql-server.asp) that has a number of scripts for dealing with dropping/adding unnamed constraints.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to resort to dynamic SQL.

Bear in mind though that any data that was previously set by the old default will remain.

```
DECLARE @query varchar(256)

SET @query = (
    SELECT 'ALTER TABLE my_table DROP CONSTRAINT ' + d.name 
    FROM sysobjects d
        INNER JOIN sysobjects t ON t.id = d.parent_obj
    WHERE d.type = 'D'
        AND t.name = 'my_table')

EXEC(@query)

ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_date_column default getdate() for date_column
```

EDIT: Where multiple default columns exist in my_table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Defaults (
    strName varchar(256) PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT INTO #Defaults (strName)
SELECT d.name 
FROM sysobjects d
    INNER JOIN sysobjects t ON t.id = d.parent_obj
WHERE d.type = 'D'
    AND t.name = 'my_table'

DECLARE @name varchar(256), @query varchar(256)

SET @name = (SELECT TOP 1 strName FROM #Defaults)

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN        
    SET @query = 'ALTER TABLE my_table DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @name

    EXEC(@query)

    DELETE FROM #Defaults 
    WHERE strName = @name

    SET @name = (SELECT TOP 1 strName FROM #Defaults)
END

ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_date_column1 default getdate() for date_column1

ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_date_column2 default getdate() for date_column2

DROP TABLE #Defaults
```

Comment: Won't that query return one row for every default constraint defined on `my_table`?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes. I didn't realize you had multiple default constraints. I'll edit in a sec.